# IP address has negative reputation/is suspicious. What to do?

Tags: networking, ip

Lately many websites ask if I'm a robot and let my answer a chapta. I checked my IP address on different websites and most of them say it is suspicious or has negative reputation. What is the best thing to do now?

Further information: I often use private mode of firefox. I don't use any proxy. My network is shared by two PCs and two mobile devices. All connected devices are neither infected nor have illegal software installed. I downloaded a lot lately and streamed videos, but nothing illegal or malicious.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Tell us more about your network. Is it a private network? Is it yours? Who else uses it?

Comment: Do you have a dynamic IP? If so, you may have picked up an IP address, previously allocated to someone who used it inappropriately. If you power your router off and on, you should get a new IP without such a history.

Comment: I've never head of a website rating a home user's IP as suspicious.

Comment: @AFH I will turn off my router for some time. If I just restart it, my IP doens't change.

Comment: @Davi Schwartz My family uses it. I asked them if they have downloaded anything lately, but none of them has. The network is just a router with two PCs and wifi. All wifi devices are known (my phone and a tablet).

Answer (score 3):

I've never head of a website rating a home user's IP as suspicious. I would not pay too much mind to it. There are alot of fake security websites out there, feeding people all sorts of misinformation or robot gathered/auto generated information. They basically take advantage of common keywords used in google to attract visitors. The pages are  literally engineered to give you fake content based on the keyword you used. Their aims are to make ad money, trick you into downloading trojan infested binaries or fishing.

Fact of the matter, websites are putting in anti-robot and human verification as a matter course and are applying the checks to everyone, not just you. They'll do it to make sure no automated account signups happen, wallpaper websites will do a check every 20 downloads to ensure that they're not being auto downloaded by some robot, even Virus Total will check if you're human.

If you're really concerned about it, take your laptop to the library and browse the websites that are giving you checks. See if it persists.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. Even symantec (Norton Security) tells me, that my IP has negative reputation. And I have never experience robot checks before (exept for accounr creation). I get those checks even on  stack exchange.

Comment: Very strange. First I hear about this. Problem is you can't really control your IP's reputation as you assigned a dynamic IP by your ISP which changes every few hours and get's passed along to someone else. Your PC might be clean but someone else using your ISP might have a backdoored one that's having a robot run out of it without know it. If you have a laptop you can try the following test to make sure it's not you. Take it to a library try to reproduce. If it reproduces in a library. Boot up  with a Ubuntu live USB stick to see if still persists.  (continued =>)

Comment: (=> continued) If checks persist under all these conditions, then it's really not you or your ISP. If checks stop happening in the library using your windows, then it's your ISP. If checks stop happening when you boot into Ubuntu and browse with it, then something is happening in your Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure but the IP might have been used previously or being used for sending abusive or malicious emails.  This is not always be the case.  By the way I too never heard of this. Lastly, where did you check the reputation?

Answer (score -2):

If you would like you could try acquring a new ip address. Assuming you are on windows you could do that in cmd prompt with:
`ipconfig /release`
`ipconfig /renew`

Comment: That *might* get a new IP address on the local network, it will have no effect whatsoever on the external IP of the network.

Comment: I have heard that for some people reinstalling your network adapter works. Do you think this could work? @Tyson

Comment: No. Windows or its local machine can't solve this. The router is obtaining the external IP that is allegedly tainted.

Comment: Hi @Pythonic, I think your mixing up the local or internal IP you get on a Network and the ISP assigned one that registers when you browse the net. The former changes with ipconfig, the latter is completely independent. He'd have to get on Torr or use a proxy service to change his IP.